# Failed to start after modifying mongodb dbpath

Tags: linux, mongodb

I executed the following command to modify the dbpath:

```
mkdir /mnt/data/mongodb
sudo chown -R mongod:mongod /mnt/data/mongodb
```

Modify mongod.conf:

```
vi /etc/mongod.conf

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /mnt/data/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
```

But when I restart mongodb it fails.

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

The following is the error log:

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since 四 2020-10-15 21:56:26 UTC; 1min 43s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 11144 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=100)
  Process: 11142 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 11140 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 11139 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 10605 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

10月 15 21:56:26 centos-sfo2-04 systemd[1]: Starting MongoDB Database Server...
10月 15 21:56:26 centos-sfo2-04 mongod[11144]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
10月 15 21:56:26 centos-sfo2-04 mongod[11144]: forked process: 11147
10月 15 21:56:26 centos-sfo2-04 systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=100
10月 15 21:56:26 centos-sfo2-04 systemd[1]: Failed to start MongoDB Database Server.
10月 15 21:56:26 centos-sfo2-04 systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
10月 15 21:56:26 centos-sfo2-04 systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
```

Comment: Possibly related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45691032/mongod-service-start-exits-with-code-100)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command

```
sudo mongod --dbpath /mnt/data/mongodb --repair
```

And also please check the permission of the directory path.

Comment: I executed `sudo chown -R mongod:mongod /mnt/data/mongodb` and `sudo mongod --dbpath /mnt/data/mongodb --repair`, but still can't start

Comment: use 'sudo mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf --repair ' and let me know

Comment: @xiandanin can you please check DB path permission with the previous path, I had the permission issue with the DB path. After that first stop, the database then try to start it again.

Comment: Still not working. I changed back to the default directory (`/var/lib/mongo`) and it can run normally. `/mnt/data` is the new mounted partition, but I need `/mnt/data` as the data directory

Comment: The permissions are as follows:  ```drwxr-xr-x. 4 mongod mongod  4096 10月 16 07:09 mongodb```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the data path permission and ownership,

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/log/mongodb
```

and then change the data directory,

```
mongod --dbpath /data/mongo
```